# Alternative to 'ban' for Varnish 2.x

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, fastly, fastly-vcl

We are using below code in **Varnish 4.x**:

```
 if (req.http.X-Pool) {
    ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
 }
```

Now we are moving to Fastly which uses **Varnish 2.x**, so we are not getting what is the alternative to ban in Varnish 2.x

Answer (score 1):

For help with Fastly Varnish/VCL I recommend reading through both:

- https://developer.fastly.com/
- https://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/fastly-varnish/

I would also generally recommend reaching out to support@fastly.com (they're a good group of people).

With regards to your question, I'm unfamiliar with `bans` in standard Varnish, but reading through https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/purging.html#bans it suggests that a ban is a way to prevent *cached* content from being served.

So the solution depends on what you're trying to achieve when that happens.

If you just want to avoid the cache you can return a `pass` from the various subroutines like `vcl_recv` and `vcl_hit` (although from vcl_hit will cause a [hit-for-pass](https://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/fastly-varnish/#hit-for-pass) and so that will cause the request to go straight to the backend.

You could also add custom logic to either `vcl_recv` or maybe even [`vcl_hit`](https://developer.fastly.com/reference/vcl/subroutines/hit/)  (if you want to be sure the content requested was actually cached) and from there you could trigger an `error` which would send you to `vcl_error` where you could construct a synthetic response:

```
sub vcl_hit {
  #FASTLY hit

  if (<some_condition>) {
    error 700
  }
}
sub vcl_error {
  #FASTLY error

  if (obj.status == 700) {
    set obj.status = 404;

    synthetic {"
      <!doctype html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Error</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>404 Not Found (varnish)</h1>
        </body>
      </html>
      "};

    return(deliver);
  }
```

Alternatively from either `vcl_recv` or `vcl_hit` you might want to `restart` and then have a check for the restart and do something different (change the backend or the request in some way):

```
sub vcl_recv {
  #FASTLY recv

  if (req.restarts > 0) {
    if (<some_condition>) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```